# What did it mean these symbols (& ~ |) when use font class

Tags: c#

I have the following code

```
Font oldf;
Font newf;

oldf = this.richText.SelectionFont;

if (oldf.Bold)
  newf = new Font(oldf, oldf.Style & ~FontStyle.Bold);
else
  newf = new Font(oldf, oldf.Style | FontStyle.Bold);
```

I know that code, but I don't know what did it mean these symbols &,| and ~ .
is these mean ( and , or , not ) or Am I wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like others have stated, they are bitwise operators.  `FontStyle` is a bit field (set of flags).

---

```
oldf.Style & ~FontStyle.Bold
```

This means "remove bold" but looking at the underlying math, you get *something like this*.

```
(a) FontStyle.Bold  = 0b00000010;  // just a guess, it doesn't really matter
(b) oldf.Style      = 0b11100111;  // random mix here
// we want Bold "unset"
(c) ~FontStyle.Bold = 0b11111101;
=> (b) & (c)        = 0b11100101;  // oldf without Bold
```

---

```
new Font(oldf, oldf.Style | FontStyle.Bold)
```

This means that we want to Bold the font. By OR'ing it with the exist value (this also means that something that's already bold will remain bold).

```
(a) FontStyle.Bold  = 0b00000010;  // just a guess, it doesn't really matter
(b) oldf.Style      = 0b11100000;  // random mix here
=> (b) | (c)        = 0b11100010;  // oldf with Bold
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

[& is the logical and](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

[| is the logical or](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxszd0kx%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Check those links out for descriptions.

[Click here to view All C# Operator descriptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

They are bitwise operations.  `|` is OR `&` is AND, and `~` is NOT.

You're comparing flags of an enumeration, so each one of those (`Style`, `Bold`, etc.) is a number that is some power of two.  The magic of bit manipulation with flags such as that is that a bitwise OR of two flags will have two bits set.  By using bit masking someone can figure out which values you OR-ed together, or whether or not a particular 'enumeration' was used.

The first line is asking for a font with `Style` set to true AND that's NOT `Bold`.

The second is looking for a font with `Style` OR `Bold`.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, they are logical bitwise operators.

```
new Font(oldf, oldf.Style & ~FontStyle.Bold);
```

Has the effect of removing the bold attribute from your overall style (these always seemed a bit backwards to me when I began, having to AND something to get rid of it, but you'll get used to it).

```
new Font(oldf, oldf.Style | FontStyle.Bold);
```

ORing will add the bold enum to your style.

Do a bit of reading and then work out what is happening with a bit of paper, it is pretty clever and this sort of coding is used all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

They are the logical bitwise operators.

This:

```
newf = new Font(oldf, oldf.Style & ~FontStyle.Bold);
```

Is taking the old font style and removing bold by performing a bitwise AND with every bit EXCEPT (bitwise negate) bold.

However this:

```
newf = new Font(oldf, oldf.Style | FontStyle.Bold);
```

Is setting the bit represented by FontStyle.Bold.

Answer (score 0):

Those are bitwise operators: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d%28v=vs.71%29.aspx (the row "Logical (boolean and bitwise)")

Basically, they work on the bit level. & is AND, | is OR, ~ is NOT. Here's an example:

```
00000001b & 00000011b == 00000001b (any bits contained by both bytes)
00000001b | 00001000b == 00001001b (any bits contained in either byte)
~00000001b == 11111110b (toggle all bits)
```

I used single bytes here, but it works for multibyte values as well.

Answer (score 0):

The variables are bitflag enumerations. So you can and them together with the bitwise AND operator "$" or OR them together with the bitwise OR Operator "|".

They're used with enumeration so allow you to specify multiple options example below.

```
[Flags]
enum Numbers {
  one = 1   // 001
  two = 2   // 010
  three = 4 // 100
}   

var holder = Numbers.two | Numbers.one; //one | two == 011

if ((holder & Numbers.one) == Numbers.one) {
  //Hit
}

if ((holder & Numbers.two) == Numbers.two) {
  //Hit
}

if ((holder & Numbers.three) == Numbers.three) {
  //Not hit in this example
}
```